# is there such thing as resetting radio button?

Tags: c#

i would like to create a reset button that will unchecked the checked radiobutton in windows form.. can i just clear it by using radiobutton.Clear();?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not

```
radiobutton.Checked = false
```

?

Besides I don't see a `Clear()` method for `System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton`.

Comment: i tried this but when i click the reset button my radio button is still unchecked

Comment: i have created a new form and use radiobutton.Checked = false ,it works..i think the reason it didnt unchecked on my other form just now b/c i put my radiobutton in panel.. probably i need to call the panel before unchecked the radiobutton..anyway thanks for helping ^^

Answer (score 0):

`radiobutton.Checked = false;`

Answer (score 0):

```
radioButton1.Checked = false;
```

[Ref.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this to clear the Radiobutton or RadiobuttonList

```
Radiobutton.ClearSelection();
```

its working..